# How to get the total rows of JSON table?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I just want to ask how to get the total current rows of JSON table. I am newbie in JSON so Im hoping someone would answer my question. Thank you..

Comment: post your json please. what you mean by json table? is it an array?

Comment: in my understanding if you have a table in your JSON object it means you have an array of arrays. To get the number of "rows" just do myJsonObject.length. Or did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[0].firstName + " " + obj.employees[0].lastName;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```